# Without an action in controller how does rails execute the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I just started learning rails. I have a doubt in the following section.

Controller:

`book_controller.rb`

```
 class BookController < ApplicationController
 end
```

View:

```
list.html.erb  

 <% if @books.blank? %>
<p>There are not any books currently in the system.</p>
<% else %>
<p>These are the current books in our system</p>
<ul id="books">
<% @books.each do |c| %>
<li><%= link_to c.title, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} -%></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Router:

```
get 'list' => 'book#list'
```

When I goto `localhost:3000/list`, it displays the content of `list.html.erb`. How does that happen when I don't have an `list` action in Controller? How is my understanding wrong?

Comment: That Rails handle automatically... Your route know which controller to which action to go.. and from there which default view has to be displayed.. if all conventions right there, things will work without any disturb, as you see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the @books is defined in the book controller there is no trouble executing this code since the list.html.erb is already define inside the books folder and the route is set as

```
get 'list' => 'book#list'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby MVC structure is integrated such that when you create a variable `@varibale` it is already available at view.